# Separate Properties file for circuit breaker of Resilience 4j

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, resilience4j

Whether it is possible to have seperate properties file for circuit breaker of Resilience 4j in spring boot with maven as build tool. If so kindly provide the suggestions . Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can have as many files as you want, check the spring boot docs on how to load additinal property files.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach additional properties using `spring.config.location` flag.

In your runtime arguments:
`-Dspring.config.location=classpath:/,C:/app-properties/additional.properties`